# deletion of file using if argument with multiple variable in linux

Tags: linux

i just created an argument using IF loop, with the loop i have multiple variables in it. it just happen that only with filename starts with CN are deleted but under the filename under CA are not deleted.

here's my code, appreciate your help. THANKS ! :)

```
    if [ "$retval" = true ]

    then
    for file_name in "$processdir"/*?.?*; do
        filebasename=$(basename "$file_name")

    if [ "$prefix" == "CA" ] || [ "$prefix" == "CN" ];


    then

    rm -f "$file_name"

    retval_1="true"     

    fi


done
```

fi

Answer (score 0):

You never affect `$prefix`. I think you don't need this variable

Try this :

```
if [ "$retval" = true ]
then
    for file_name in "$processdir"/*
    do
        filebasename=$(basename "$file_name")

        if [[ "$filebasename" == "CA*" ]] || [[ "$filebasename" == "CN*" ]]
        then    
            rm -f "$file_name"    
            retval_1="true"       
        fi
    done
fi
```

Comment: dont want to confuse you, its my first time to write a comment, my reply for the code is at the top for convenience of viewing my edited code. thanks ! 
i just try out your given code but both files are not deleted :(

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the feedback, but i just used the $prefix for looking up on the filenames that starts with "CA" or "CN"  and also for the naming convention of my directory.

here is my edited code:

```
    if [ "$retval" = true ]

    then
    for file_name in "$processdir$prefix"/*
do

    filebasename=$(basename "$file_name")
    prefix=${filebasename:0:2}



    if [ "$prefix" == "CA" ]|| [ "$prefix" == "CN" ];


    then

    rm -iv "$file_name"

    retval_1="true"     

    fi


done
```

fi